# Apply XSLT based on a condition

Tags: xslt-1.0

Let's say I have an XML like below.

```
<CUSTOMER_ORDER>
    <MSG_DATE><?MSG_DATE>
    <DOCUMENT_TYPE></DOCUMENT_TYPE>
</CUSTOMER_ORDER>
```

let's imagine that I have a XSLT as well.

I want to apply this transformer only if DOCUMENT_TYPE = 'S'. Is there any way I can achieve this in the XSLT??

Comment: No, but you can write your stylesheet so that it produces one result when the condition is true and a different (or empty) result otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="//DOCUMENT_TYPE='S'">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of `<xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:otherwise>`?

Comment: @michael.hor257k sir user can write another condition if you want